# Get.OpenFilename array + 'For Each' or 'Do While'?

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning!

I've only been learning VBA for a week now... Like drinking from a waterfall. Despite research I cannot seem to put this together. This sub is to open multiple selected sheets, edit as needed, until all sheets are edited.

I am using the GetOpenFilename to capture multiple files, which I then want to have opened and run through my StandaloneReportEdit macro - I am unsure why I cannot call the created array, or what I should research to figure that out:

```
Dim my_FileName As Variant

my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    filefilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*", _
    Title:="Select Excel File to Open", _
    MultiSelect:=TRUE)

If my_FileName = False Then End

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(my_FileName, False, False)

Call StandaloneReportEdit 'Sub to very thoroughly edit reports
```

Where I would use 'For Each' (or perhaps Do While), I cannot quite figure out what to reference... Would something like this work?

```
For Each my_FileName 'Call StandaloneReportEdit here
```

Or should I use 'Do While' as in the following:

```
Do While my_FileName = True

    If my_FileName = False Then End

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(my_FileName, False, False)

Call StandaloneReportEdit

Loop
```

This question might not be as thorough as you all might like, and I apologize, I think I'm missing something and just being pointed in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Avoid `End`. Use `Exit Sub` instead of nuking the whole execution context. It's not clear what you're trying to iterate with `my_FileName`, nor exactly what your question is. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: If you're getting multiple file names and you're trying to iterate them, you can quite easily rephrase your post to say so. Don't apologize, just fix it! ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I'm trying to capture the array of files selected from the .GetOpenFilename above, so that I can run through all of them with the sub called in. I'll edit to clarify, I think I'm utterly lost though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For Each` is the easiest, but you need another variable to get the name from the array. Also testing for `False` will not work well for a variable of type `Variant` (even though the documentation [suggests it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx#Anchor_2)). Better use `IsArray()` for that:

```
Sub doIt()
    Dim myFileName As Variant
    Dim myFileNames As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook

    myFileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*", _
        Title:="Select Excel File to Open", _
        MultiSelect:=True)

    If Not IsArray(myFileNames) Then Exit Sub

    For Each myFileName In myFileNames
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFileName, False, False)
        StandaloneReportEdit() 'Sub to very thoroughly edit reports
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: OH! I think I see... I designate the array created as a variable? Based on the total selection of files, which are each a 'variable' in the array, and for each file selected it will run through the macro, next, until done and end?

Comment: While arrays *can* be iterated with `For Each`, and this is clearly not going to be a performance bottleneck (`Workbooks.Open` should be the Big One here, unless `StandaloneReportEdit` is utterly inefficient), iterating an array with a `For` loop gives (much) better performance; use `For Each` to iterate object collections, `For` to iterate arrays.

Comment: @dduz, you phrase it a bit odd, but yes, the variable `myFileName` takes the value of each string in the `myFileNames` array variable, as the loop iterates over it.

Comment: @trincot - Yea, I probably do... I only just started learning this 7 days ago so my phrasing is off. Thank you a ton for your response, I have been able to utilize this to learn how to do some really cool new things.